# Batch Loop Through All Files And Subfolders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, encode, subdirectory

So I Am Working On Multiple Batch Programs and I need to know how to loop through all files including files inside the sub-folders. However, I was unable to do so. One of these programs that requires this is using the command "certutil -encode" which encodes all files in that folder and sub-folders and decode with the command "certutil -decode" and here is the code I got so far (this code is in a loop):

```
set file=C:\Extras\Encode\*.txt
certutil -encode C:\Extras\Encode\*.txt C:\Extras\Encoded\*.b64
```

However this doesn't work since it only loops through C:\Extras\Encode but doesn't test for the ones inside sub-folders like C:\Extras\Encode\Subfolder\ so what do I do?

**EDIT**: I know the second part with the output being C:\Extras\Encoded*.hex is wrong.

Comment: Take a look at `for /R` to loop through a directory tree recursively; `for /R /D` dies the same but enumerates all directories rather than files; type `for /?` in the command prompt for details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "C:\extras\encode\*.txt"') do echo %%a
```

should provide %%a with each filename matching the mask in the subtree. You could use the modified references %%~da %%~pa %%~na %%~xa %%~dpnxa for the drive,path,name,extension or all-in-combination as you will.

Details will vary depending on application.

Comment: This worked out great except when I do this, it sets %%a as multiple files and using "certutil -encode" is not possible since those are too many arguments for it to handle at once, how do I bypass this? Should I post this as another question?

Comment: I'm no expert in `certutil` - I've never used it. Perhaps in place of `echo %%a` you could try `certutil -encode C:\Extras\Encode\%%~na.txt C:\Extras\Encoded\%%~na.b64` which should run a different `certutil` instance on each file serially. There doesn't appear to be an option to provide `certutil` with a list of files. Run on a small subset first to see how it goes. `%%~na` means the name-part of `%%a`. You may want `%%~nxa` which means the name+extension of `%%a`.